# VisualAge cpprbi40.dll doesn't work in Windows 10 version 20h2

Tags: windows, dll, updates, visual-age

I developed some applications in VisualAge for Windows in C++ many years ago. The application is running in the Windows 10 Version 2004, but not in the version 20H2 anymore.
I get the error message ccprbi40.dll cannot executed, error status 0xc0000005.
Do you have any idea, what was changed, and how can I bring to work in the 20H2 version?

Comment: That product was discontinued in 2007.  You are lucky you've gotten anything out of it in 13 years after its death.  I think it's time to  use a modern, up-to-date IDE.

Comment: Update the code to use a more current compiler.  I recommend [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/).  (IBM Visual Age's successor IBM XL C/C++ does not appear to support Windows.)

Comment: It is not easy, because another class library should be used. The VisualAge class libaray is totally different. I use since 20 years the Visual Studio for new development.